# Emitting Transfer Event even when there is no actual transfer

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, ether

I am new to smart contracts and trying to understand it so that i can detect Ether transfers done to my user via Smart Contract.

I know I can find the event emitted from topics[]. But for those contracts where i don't have there code, but i can deduce from the topic[] that a Transfer or AssetWithdrawal , etc, event was emitted, how can i be sure that when Transfer event was emitted actual transfer of asset took place(since i don't have that contract's code)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to trust the contract.  The idea is that contract's code is public (byte code, I mean), so everybody may analyse it and decide, whether to trust it.  The reality is that byte code is unreadable, so people anslyse source code instead, and then ensure, that compiling that source code produce exactly the same byte code as published on chain (here people assume, that byte code, produced by the compiler behaves in the same way as written in the source code, i.e. trust compiler).  Moreover, people usually delegate the latter check to [Etherscan.io}[1](https://etherscan.io/).

So, however in theory smart contract should allow trustless ecosystem, in harsh reality people  still have to trust developers of Solidity compiler and admins of [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/).

This situation could be fixed by using human-readable byte code.  Maybe some day in some blockchain this will be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure whether you really mean Ether transfers or (ERC20) token transfers. Ether transfers don't emit any events (unless some contract happens to emit upon receiving Ethers). If you transfer Ether between EOA (Externally Owned Account) without contracts there will certainly be no events emitted.

So let me provide an answer for both cases, just in case.

**Ether**

This is rather easy. You can't rely on any events emitted but you can simply look at the transaction and see if it has associated value attached. Ethers are always transferred with the `value` field (you can see an example here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x94cd1f32992d07810d2ccadf8839fa3098e2883e16ab0e7163a5d0b255d3539e)

**(ERC20) token**

If you are talking about ERC20 tokens they typically should emit the `Transfer` event when tokens have been transferred. However there is no way to determine for sure whether they always do that (and are therefore fully ERC20 compliant or not).

If you want to be sure you can't trust on the event. You have to check for the actual token transfer. Even that may be a bit tricky: you either have to compare balances before and after the transaction or then try to analyze the contract bytecode and the sent data to see if it triggered token transfer. Such analysis might be rather...difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that quick response.
I would like to clear my question. Suppose for this transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x89221691a67b15427c97f1fd0cd65966ff617728cd897be27d88a04ee0bc1e2d
Ether is being transferred via Contract. All I get to know from the contract's event list is that the event `Transacted` was emitted. I want to be sure about the authenticity of the event emitted, whether its a valid emit or just random emit from any line of code.
Should I consider those contracts which are not verified on Etherscan?

Comment: Clear your question in your question, not in an answer to it.

Comment: And BTW, the user who you seem to be referring to at the top of your answer here did not get a notification for it. You'll have to do it in a comment to that user's answer.

Comment: Shady contract code!! Anyways.. the contract need not be compliant to any of the standards to do a value transfer.. Example is opensea contract(0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b
). This is a marketpalce contract which need not be compliant on any standard